# Is there any API available for Naruto?

Tags: naruto

I came across this Pokemon API service: http://pokeapi.co/

Just want to know is there any API available for Naruto anime?

Comment: Unless there is a Naruto *game* you are referring to, there isn't an equivalent one since the site you linked is about the Pokemon ***game*** not the anime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet you're planning to make a fan-based naruto game, so instead of searching for API, you should first gather information such as character's stats. These websites provide detailed information about each ninjas:

[Full characters' biography and stats](http://www.leafninja.com/biographies.php)
[Full characters' biography, history and stats (Naruto wikia)](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Characters)

And then, you can apply those stats and info just like http://pokeapi.co/ do.